# n distinct books need to be packed into m identical boxes

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Each box must contain at least one book, and books are packed all facing the same way, as they would be on a shelf. In how many ways can we pack the boxes?

I think that this is the composition of n books into m parts, all positive with the books being ordered, so the total number would be $n!\binom{n-1}{m-1}$. Is this the right logic? Or is there a part that I am missing, thank you!

Comment: Does order within a box matter?

Comment: Assuming that order within a box doesn't matter, this would be the [stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) $\left\{\begin{smallmatrix}n\\m\end{smallmatrix}\right\}$

Comment: @JMoravitz I think so, the books are in some sort of order before being put in the box, so the boxes are distinguished by the books they contain

Comment: Well, yes, I understand that the boxes are distinguished by the books they contain, but the question is whether or not order *within* the box matters.  For example, I understand that the arrangement $(1~2)(3~4)$ is considered the same as $(3~4)(1~2)$ when arranging four books into two boxes., but is this also the same as the arrangement $(1~2)(4~3)$?

Comment: @JMoravitz Oh, then no I don't think the order within the box matters. How would this make it S(n,m)?

Comment: @saulspatz follow the conversation in the comments above.  The answer of $n!\binom{n-1}{m-1}$ is only correct in the case that boxes are distinct and order within a box matters.  As for why it would be $S(n,m)$, this is *precisely* the situation that stirling numbers of the second kind are meant to count.  The number of ways to partition an $n$ element set into $m$ unlabeled nonempty subsets (*noting that order of the subsets and order within the subsets are both irrelevant*).

Comment: @JMoravitz Ok I understand! If the boxes are NOT distinct, but the order within the box matters, then what would this turn into? Because if my answer above only works for distinct boxes, I don't know what this would turn the answer into...

Comment: Hmm... that becomes a much more involved question that honestly I don't have an answer to.  My first instinct would have been to try to correct your approach using [restricted partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) in place of stars-and-bars, but this incorrectly overcounts scenarios where multiple boxes have the same number of books in them.  (*There is clearly only one way to distribute five books into five identical boxes with none empty, not $5!$ ways*).  Some special cases are easy to find, such as two boxes as $n!(n-1)-n!/2$ if $n$ even, $n!(n-1)$ if odd.

Comment: Argh! Can we stop wrapping clear and short counting problems into unnatural stories that can be read in 8 different ways?

Comment: @darijgrinberg if it were "clear" then it couldn't be read in different ways.

Comment: Well, whoever posed it must have had a clear problem in mind before garbling it, hopefully...

Comment: I've figured it out- since the boxes are distinguished by only books they contain, any permutation of the boxes would change it's contents, so we can divide what I have originally by m! to remove these options, so the answer would be: $\frac{n!}{m!} \binom{n-1}{m-1}$